# Alias scope in service manager config

Tags: php, configuration, zend-framework2

I have been using ZF2 for a few months now, but I am still far from being an expert.

My question of the day is about the service manager configuration, and more precisely about aliases.
I know that the configuration is merged at execution time, but I was wondering if this remains true for aliases or are they scoped within the module in which they are declared?

Thanks in advance for anyone who could help me with this!

Okin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aliases throughout the whole application, so yes, they are as global as all other invokables or factories, too.